# What is the most efficient way to create views using Job DSL so that I do not have Job names mentioned in multiple places

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

In my current team, we are creating Job DSL scripts for converting our Jenkins jobs and views into code.
We have quite a large number of jobs in our Jenkins. While doing this I noticed that we have to specify the job name in 2 places, first in the actual DSL script which have the necessary code for your job and the second one is in the view method to add this job to the respective view.
One of the drawback in doing this is, in future if I need to change the job name for one of my jobs, I will have to change it in both these places.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this..

In general are there any best practices that I could follow while doing this.

Answer (score 2):

While creating views using job dsl you can also specify regex pattern matching the job names instead of adding all jobs into view if you are following a naming convention.
This will also avoid updating new jobs in view dsl when adding more jobs.

Comment: Agree. Follow a proper job (and view) naming convention, typically a multi-part name (ymmv on categorization), then set up regex that match. Manually populating views is counterproductive.